How to delete non root-owned files from Unix /tmp folder
We have some Ubuntu v22 servers that get a lot of files dumped into the /tmp directory, in spite of our best code efforts to clean up after the processes are done.  What we would like to do is run a process via cron that cleans up our files similar to the way it is cleaned out when the server restarts; in that it doesn't delete all of the root owned files. I've tried variations of rm -rf, but they delete everything, not just our files.
To complicate matters, the file name structures for our temp files vary widely, e.g. some don't have extensions, the name length and structures are very long vs short etc.
In looking at the file ownership of all the files, all the ones that we want deleted are owned by the ubuntu user and group, and the ones we want to leave are owned by root
Is there either a) a way to run the same cleanup process that the server runs on startup, or b) a way with find or `rm to target files to remove by user/group owner?


Is there a way to run the same cleanup process that the server runs on startup

The "cleanup" process is effectively rm -rf /tmp. In actuality, most modern distributions mount /tmp as a tmpfs filesystem -- that means it's a memory-based filesystem; the files there aren't stored on disk and it all just disappears when the server reboots. When the system boots up it starts with an empty /tmp directory.

Is there a way with find or `rm to target files to remove by user/group owner?

Sure, that's what the find command is for. The simple version is going to be:
find /tmp -user foo -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf

A slightly more careful version might be:
# First remove all the files
find /tmp -user foo -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f

# Then (attempt to) remove all the now empty directories
find /tmp -user foo -type d -print0 | xargs -0 rmdir

See man find and man xargs for more information.
